# Unable to install easyocr and torch on Fedora 37

Tags: python, pytorch, ocr, fedora

I tried installing torch and  `easyocr` on a Fedora 37 machine. I used the following command: `pip install easyocr`, `pip install torch`. But I was not able to install torch although `easyocr` gets downloaded. I  would like to know if there is any issue with torch.

Command: `pip install easyocr` on Fedora 37.

Comment: What was the error for torch installation?

Comment: It said "collecting torch" and then "Killed"

Comment: Yes, that's the main problem. A single "Killed" message generally means that there's not enough RAM. Could you check your RAM usage when installing torch?

Comment: Thank you for your  clarification. I tried to look at the ram usage. it peaked to 100% and then the installation stops. I have 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I will edit my answer if the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 GB RAM which is quite low. It should install with this command:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir torch
```

If anyone is experiencing the same issue, they should check this thread:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25164

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the previous answer, i can attest that the command

`pip --no-cache-dir install easyocr`

Will work as intended on a fairly limited system, memory-wise.

Here's a cast showing how i installed it, on F37, using the previous command. Cast is real-time and my internet connection is very average so...

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Nice shell prompt lol.